# Prevent padding from making an element bigger?

Tags: html, css, layout, padding

I have an element with a `70%` width, and it is floating beside another element with `30%` width. However, when I add `25px` of padding, the element expands and breaks the format.

Is there any way to make padding increase the contents' distance from the element's edge, as opposed to making the element bigger?

```css
.seventy {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.thirty {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.padded {
  padding: 25px; /* Forces box onto next line */
}
```

```html
<div>Works:</div>
<div class="seventy">70% wide</div>
<div class="thirty">30% wide</div>

<br><br>

<div>Broken:</div>
<div class="seventy">70% wide</div>
<div class="thirty padded">30% wide, padded</div>
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When you use the `border-box` model, the padding is included in the box size. See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/box.html) for details.

```css
.seventy {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

.thirty {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 25px;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="seventy">70% wide</div>
<div class="thirty">30% wide</div>
```

Comment: Although corrext the support for box-sizing is a bit sketchy. Consider taking a small percentage off one of the widths and adding it to the padding. So your 2 widths+padding = 100%. EDIT~ Zeta Twos solution will guarentee a gap of 25px which would be a better solution.

Answer (score 11):

I would create another element of the same type (may I guess it's a div?) inside the element and set that one to have a padding/margin of 25px.

For example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="width30">
 </div>
 <div id="width70">
  <div id="padding25">
   Acctual content here.
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a super smart solution people should take account of more.  There's no sketchy css hacks, no potentially unsupported browsers, and it follows a clean container-content pattern.  Glad to see some KISS CSS (CISS?), since it's so easy to over-engineer.