# How to put inside padding inside div on two column layout

Tags: html, css

This is my cut down code: http://jsfiddle.net/rCBL9/

I want to put `padding: 10px;` so I have a 10px spacing on the inside of the white boxes, but when I add this it makes the outside of the white boxes bigger.

How can add a 10px spacing on the inside of the white boxes without making them larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by giving the elements a `box-sizing:border-box;` which changes the way the CSS box model is calculated.

Basically, the width/height of any element is the specified width/height plus any margins, paddings and borders.  When you change the box-sizing of an element to "border-box", all the extra widths (the borders/margins/paddings) are deducted from the specified width/height.

Here is a good read about how the box-model works: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

I updated the fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/rCBL9/2/

Answer (score 2):

By using `box-sizing: border-box;` you will get the result you desire.

```
.left { padding: 10px; box-sizing: border-box;  }
```

Also, unlike other poster, I'll give credit to previous poster, found here;

[keep padding from making the element bigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175268/keep-padding-from-making-the-element-bigger)